Import packages cloned locally instead of PyPI
I had previously installed a package on PyPI via pip, but then cloned the same repo locally to make some changes.
I'm now trying to import the package from the GitHub repo locally, yet it seems to be importing the PyPI version of the package.
How do I only import packages cloned locally?
I'm new to using git, so apologies for using the wrong terminology.

Since you have a modified copy of the package, I assume you no longer want the PyPi copy. To achieve what you want, you can uninstall the PyPi package and then install the locally modified copy of the package using
python -m pip install /path/to/package/

With this, you will be able to install the modified copy of the package and use it as you as were using the PyPi copy. You can also choose to import the package modules without installing them by moving the package directory to a directory relative to your project directory but that too requires the uninstallation of the PyPi package.
